# MVC Razor custom checkbox updating 'real' checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I am a novice, so please bear with me here. I am working on a form in MVC and want to have a custom checkbox. I kind of find my way to get it working the way I want by:

- hiding the form checkbox
- keep using the label of the checkbox to display its purpose
- inserting a html label and input in combination with a script to get the checkbox value relayed

The relevant section of my view looks as follows:

```
<div id="loginRememberMeArea" class="formCheckBoxArea col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @id = "loginRememberMeField", @class = "formCheckBoxField" })
    <input id="loginRememberMeCheckBoxHelper" class="formCheckBoxHelper" type="checkbox" value="checkbox1" name="" />
    <label id="loginRememberMeCheckBox" class="formCheckBox" for="loginRememberMeCheckBoxHelper"></label>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @id = "loginRememberMeLabel", @class = "formCheckBoxLabel" })
</div>
```

And I am using this script to do the 'magic':

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").bind('click', function () {
            var $t = $(this),
                val = $t.val(),
                key = val.charAt(val.length - 1);
            if ($t.val() == 'checkbox'+key && $t.is(':checked')) {
                $("#loginRememberMeField").attr('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $("#loginRememberMeField").attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, this appears to work seamlessly: when I check the 'fake' checkbox, the script would make sure to check the 'real' checkbox (#loginRememberMeField) as well. It also works the opposite way, when unchecking the 'fake' checkbox, it would update the 'real' checkbox. **And then it breaks:** When re-selecting the checkbox for a second time, the 'real' checkbox would not be updated. I can't seem to find out why. Thank you in advance for your help!

**Update:**
What I did to customize the checkbox style is I have hidden the real checkbox (loginRememberMeField), leveraged a label (loginRememberMeCheckBox) to style the checkbox, placed it on top of a bound dummy checkbox (loginRememberMeCheckBoxHelper). Consequently when I click on the label (which displays a checkbox), the dummy checkbox (loginRememberMeCheckBoxHelper) gets checked. So far everything works perfectly fine for an infinite number of times. Now the script is supposed to extend the logic on the hidden, real (loginRememberMeField) checkbox so the correct value is submitted to the DB on form submission. This last piece is not working but checking/unchecking the real checkbox (loginRememberMeField) but once, after that it does not work anymore.

[Here's a link of where I got this from and where it apparently is working for an infinite number of times](http://jsfiddle.net/F7nBL/6/)

Of course I had to modify a bit, but I gave my best to keep the essentials (which I guess why it is working initially...)

Comment: It not really clear what yu are doing or why, but for a start its `$("#loginRememberMeField").prop('checked', true);`  (not `attr`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you.. the problem is not that the above is not functioning, it is that it's only working once when the site is loaded, but after checking and unchecking the checkbox, not all related fields are updated anymore. I've updated the question with a more thorough explanation.

Comment: And all your code can be done in 2 lines of code using relative selectors. And `bind` is deprecated. Use `on()` assuming you are dynamically adding elements to your view after it is first rendered

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p56jLkfx/) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke - thank you - once again, you solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StephenMuecke solved it.. changed the script to the following and now it's working perfectly fine!

```
<script>
    $('.formCheckBoxHelper').click(function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        $(this).closest('.container').find('.formCheckBoxField').prop('checked', isChecked)
    })
</script>
```